# Group up different Leaflet circleMarkers

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have over 100 leaflet markers (circleMarker). Some markers have as style `{color: '#ffffff', weight:"4"}`, some other have `{color: '#000000', weight:"4"}`. To change it later the simple way, I don't want to write it inline into the markers itself. **I just want to create two groups and a definition of styles for each of them.** Is that possible?

At the moment:

```
var markers = [];
var marker1 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{color: '#ffffff', weight:"4"}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker1);
var marker2 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{color: '#000000', weight:"3"}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker2);
var marker3 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{color: '#ffffff', weight:"4"}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker3);
var marker4 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{color: '#000000', weight:"3"}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker4);
```

What I need is something like this (Group1 & Group2):

```
var markers = [];
var marker1 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{Group1}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker1);
var marker2 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{Group2}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker2);
var marker3 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{Group1}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker3);
var marker4 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{Group2}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");
    markers.push(marker4);

var Group1 = /* some style definition */
var Group2 = /* some other style definition */
```

Is there a way to do this in leaflet?

**UPDATE:**

For everybody who is interested in the solution, it should be (based on Aesahaettr code):

```
function group1Style() {
    return {
        color: '#ffffff',
        weight:"4"
    };
}

var marker1 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],group1Style()).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");markers.push(marker1);
```

So just add your "style function" after the `latlng` directly, no `{style: ....}`.

Comment: Try the `className` option of the `L.circleMarker`

Comment: @peeebeee Good point, I will try this.

Comment: className seems not to work if I use "renderer: canvas".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to set up a specific style for a certain group and another style for the others.

You can do that using functions if you want or just a JSON you pass in the Leaflet constructor at the creation of the `Marker` :

```js
/**
 * This is the function that will be returning the style of the Group1
 */
function group1Style() {
    return {
        color: '#ffffff',
        weight:"4"
    };
}

/**
 * This is the function that will be returning the style of the Group2
 */
function group2Style() {
    return {
        color: '#000000',
        weight:"3"
    };
}

// for good practice use let instead of var
let marker1 = L.circleMarker(
        [00.000,00.000],
        {
            /**
             *  Here we pass the style as an option of the constructor
             *  I am using a condition here but you can set the style however you want
             */
            style: condition ? group1Style() : group2Style()
        }
    )
    .addTo(map)
    .on("click", circleClick)
    .bindPopup('<div>City Name</div>')
    .bindTooltip("Say hello");
    
markers.push(marker1);
```

Comment: Seems not to work for me. I tried:

var marker1 = L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{style: group1Sytle()}).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick).bindPopup
    ('<div>City Name</div>').bindTooltip("Say hello");markers.push(marker1);

Comment: You've made a typo on the style function `group1Style()` instead of `group1Sytle()`. You switched the `t` and the `y`

Comment: Just in my comment, sorry for that. In my locale code it was right and not working ;( ...

Comment: Can you share the error you got on the console ?

Comment: That's the problem, I get no error, it just ignores the group1Style().

Comment: OK, I fixed it. Instead of L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000],{style: group1Sytle()}) ... it must be L.circleMarker([00.000,00.000], group1Sytle()) ... so the "{style: ....} part killed it. But anyway, you put me on the right path! ;) Big thx!